# Facebook app tag photo of page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have Facebook page with albums and I have Facebook app.
I want that people who use my app will be able to tag photos in the albums of my page.
I use this graph api POST call:

```
PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID
```

But what happens is that the page account must confirm this tagging and also the page account that get notification about this tag so we must go photo-by-photo and look for new tagged images.

Please notice that tagging from Facebook.com website on the photos is very easy and confirmed immediately.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bnaya Livne

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same i found out that you can generate an access token for your page but when i tried it it didnt tag the person .Also i used all the permissions to generate a new access token and still page need a confirm for the tags. I think the only way is to configure ur page to be fully public.